# Convert string to date time in a `cshtml` file using razor?

Tags: c#, razor

How can I convert an `int` to `DateTime` in a `cshtml` file using razor ?

For example `date=201411` should get converted to `2014 November`.
I tried to use:

```
DateTime.TryParse(date);
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyymm");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an int but a string, however, use `MM` for the months otherwise it's minutes:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("201411", "yyyyMM", null); // null means current-culture
```

If you want the year/month use `DateTime.Year`/`DateTime.Month`:

```
int year = dt.Year;
int month = dt.Month;
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is just to create a `DateTime`:

```
  int source = 201411;
  // You can't remove the day from DateTime, so let it be the 1st Nov 2014
  DateTime result = new DateTime(source / 100, source % 100, 1);
```

To output the DateTime as `"2014 November"` use *formatting*, e.g.:

```
  //TODO: Put the right culture 
  String text = result.ToString("yyyy MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```